# Sound detection in windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, audio

I have developed an android application which detects clap sound. I wanted to port it to windows platform (c++ mainly) since I have some opencv programs as well running on Visual Studio. I have heard of portaudio software but not sure if we can do DSP in that.
I will be grateful if you could suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows Audio Session API, it is the low level sound library of Windows. Where there are several example to start to work.

It is a bit confusing at first (like everything in the complex world of Windows), but it has several useful tutorial, [capturing audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370800(v=vs.85).aspx), and [Loopback Record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx).